# Preparing SQL query statement condition using one of column of panda dataframe

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

#I would like to prepare SQL query statement using panda dataframe column in condition. Example

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'country': ['US', 'UK', 'Germany', 'China']})

#My desire output should be like

sqlquery = "select * from database where country in ('US','UK','Germany','China');"

result  = pd.read_sql(sqlquery, con=db_connection)

#But my code is not helpful with below code

query1='''select * from database where country in ('''

query2=df.country

query3=''')'''

sqlquery=query1+query2+query3
sqlquery
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_excel(r"D:\Stack_overflow\test7.xlsx")

list1=df['Country'].unique()

Sql_string='(';
for item in list1:
    Sql_string= Sql_string + " '" + str(item) + "',"
Sql_string=Sql_string[:-1] + ")"

    
query='''select * from database wjere country in'''+Sql_string+''' ; '''

print(query)
```

When You are merging query2 it might be giving errors as df.Country it does not gives string as output but gives Dataframe as output.

Hope it solves the problem.

Comment: Thank you ..But in my real implementation I am getting result as: "select * from database where country in (\'US\',\'UK\',\'Germany\',\'China\');" while those country list reading from excel file.

Comment: In your excel  file country are listed as \US\?
If not can you share the list output which is being produced by the line below.
list1=df['Country'].unique()

Comment: output for list1 is as  array(['US', 'UK', 'India', 'Pakistan', 'China'], dtype=object)

Comment: Output must be list, Then We ll be able to run the loop on list elements.
extract list from the array object using 
list1= list1[0]

Comment: I notice one more thing is '''select 
a,
b,
c,
d
from database
where country in Sql_string also producing \na, \nb \nc \nd 
'''
form...I mean here comment are in same line but making sql in multiline..output is in form \na, \nb